Access actor isolated value from another actor isolated context in Swift 6
I have the following code example
@globalActor
actor GlobalActor {
    static let shared = GlobalActor()
}

@globalActor
actor ControllerActor {
    static let shared = ControllerActor()
}

@GlobalActor
protocol MyProtocol {
    var someValue: Int { get }
    func doSomething() async
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var someValue: Int = 0
    
    func doSomething() async {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

@ControllerActor
protocol Controller {
    var myProtocol: MyProtocol? { get }
}

extension Controller {
    func doControllerWork() async  {
        await myProtocol?.doSomething()
    }
}

MyProtocol is isolated by GlobalActor, while the Controller protocol is isolated by ControllerActor. When I try to call await myProtocol?.doSomething(), I get the following error:
Sending global actor 'ControllerActor'-isolated value of type 'any MyProtocol' with later accesses to global actor 'GlobalActor'-isolated context risks causing data races.
This error disappears if doControllerWork is implemented within a class that conforms to the Controller protocol. However, in my scenario, doControllerWork is shared across multiple controllers implementations.
The issue is also resolved if I use the same actor isolation for both MyProtocol and Controller. Unfortunately, they have very different scopes within my project, so I would like to keep them isolated under separate actors.

I think restricting func doSomething() async to GlobalActor doesn't make sense. Let implementor of MyProtocol decide how to synchronise own implementation.

This is only safe if myProtocol is implemented as a stored property. If it is a computed property, it might as well be returning an instance of MyClass stored in another isolation context, and therefore you would be sending something non-sendable across isolation boundaries. In an extension, you obviously cannot tell whether a property is stored or computed, and you cannot enforce that either. Why use global actors here (two different ones, even), instead of regular actors? How are global actors related to "different scopes within your project"?

Note that putting a global actor on a protocol does not mean that every conformer of the protocol must be isolated to that global actor. Protocol implementations are free to be non-isolated, or be isolated to another global actor. The members that the protocol requires, are requried to be either isolated to the specified global actor, or be non-isolated.

@Sweeper I use dependency injection for myProtocol, so it has to be a protocol. MyProtocol has the scope of data management, while Controller has the scope of data processing

That doesn't explain why they should be isolated to different global actors.

I'm not getting a compiler warning on your sample code. I assume it's because there is not return type on your function calls. But if that's the issue you can await a Task. Take a look at these changes and see if it helps.
@globalActor
actor GlobalActor {
    static let shared = GlobalActor()
}

@globalActor
actor ControllerActor {
    static let shared = ControllerActor()
 }

@GlobalActor
protocol MyProtocol {
    var someValue: Int { get }
    func doSomething() async -> Bool
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var someValue: Int = 0

    func doSomething() async -> Bool {
        print("Hello")
        return true
    }
}

@ControllerActor
protocol Controller {
    var myProtocol: MyProtocol? { get }
}

extension Controller {
    func doControllerWork() async -> Bool {
        await Task {
            await myProtocol?.doSomething() ?? false
        }.value
    }
}

Also note that swift 6 isolation has a lot of issues for now that simply have no work arounds as a result there are options of using
nonisolated(unsafe)
and some other work arounds Apple has discussed these a bit in WWDC24 videos.

Also note you can specify an actor in a task if needed Task{ @MainActor in } although I think swift6 is moving away from that and just letting the actor isolated call make the decision.

Let me write out your code a bit more explicitly:
if let p = myProtocol {
    await p.doSomething()
}

There are three important facts here:

p is a reference that exists in the ControllerActor context
p.doSomething() implicitly passes p to doSomething as self.
doSomething executes in the GlobalActor context.

This means that p is transferred between contexts. It therefore must be Sendable. The good news is that this is already true, since all MyProtocol-conforming types are isolated to a global actor. Swift really should be able to infer this automatically, but currently cannot.
The fix is to explicitly require Sendable:
@GlobalActor
protocol MyProtocol: Sendable { ... }

This does not require any changes to conforming types since they already are Sendable. It just lets the compiler know this is true.
